# Comments missing from classes and methods from .aar file module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have a library project that I'm using to generate an .aar file and use with other projects but when I add the .aar file to a new studio project as a module I no longer can see the comments in the original code base.

When you create a library .aar file does it no longer keep the original code base's comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AAR file is similar to a Jar, both generate bytecode so that means comments are removed, that's the reason why your comments no longer appear.